# How to find city name with respect to the zip code through iphone applications

Tags: objective-c

Can any one help me in finding the city name in the map when I give zipcode through iPhone application.

Comment: How about using an IP address?

Answer (score 2):

As Deepak suggested, a Geocoding API is almost certainly the way to go.  Google and Yahoo both provide good ones that can convert zipcodes into city names.

Here's a sample Google query for zipcode: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=77048&sensor=true

And a sample Yahoo query for zipcode: http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=77048&appid=0

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any feature built-in that will help you find the city name like this. You can look at Geocoding options such a Google's [`Geocoding API`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) but then you might need a bit more info than zip code.

Answer (score 0):

Created a little native tool that looks up city, state, and lat/long without using the network connection.  Has a rather large (1.9MB) SQLite database to pull from, so don't include this if you can just query Google or another online API.

https://github.com/ocrickard/OCZipLookup