# how to find the city name with respect to the zip code in iphone

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find city name with respect to the zip code through iphone applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197548/how-to-find-city-name-with-respect-to-the-zip-code-through-iphone-applications)

I have a database that has few location details like zipcode, address, cityname, latitude and longitude. In the application i'm placing the pin in the map with respect latitude and longitude from the database with respect to zipcode which i enter. Is it possible to find the city name when i enter the zipcode which is not in the database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No it is not possible ? From where you want to find it ?

Answer (score 0):

Well obviously you need a database/web service. There is unfortunately no way of finding a city name given the zip code, if it is not stored somewhere. You can download such a database and read the file using objective-c. Or store it in some database and access it using objective-c.

Here are two links that you might be interested

http://www.boutell.com/zipcodes/

http://databases.about.com/od/access/a/zipcodedatabase.htm